# Taking Picture With Camera Android Gets Error in Eclipse

Tags: android, image

Eclipse is giving me an error with TAKE_PICTURE in the following code. I tried replacing it with CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST and got the same error. I am developing for Android 4.2 here.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.jpeg");
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

Any ideas what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is an incomplete sample code you copied from somewhere, startActivityForResult function receives an arbitrary request code that will be used by your own application later on to find out which activity has just finished, like this:

```
startActivityForResult(i, 100);
...    

startActivityForResult(i, 200);
...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 100){
        //First Activity has just finished
    }
    if (requestCode == 200){
        //Second Activity has just finished
    }
}
```

So basically, you should just define an arbitrary value for TAKE_PICTURE in your application.